# Python error TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Tags: python

I'm learning from a Book called `Hello World 2nd Edition`.

In chapter 14 page 171 I had to write a program.
This is what I wrote:

```
class HotDog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cooked_level = 0
        self.cooked_string = "Raw"
        self.condiments = []
    def __str__(self):
        msg = "hot dog"
        if len(self.condiments) > 0:
            msg = msg + "with"
        for i in self.condiments:
            msg = msg+i+", "
        msg = msg.strip(", ")
        msg = self.cooked_string + " " + msg +"."
        return msg
    def cook(self, time):
        self.cooked_level=self.cooked_level+time
        if self.cooked_level > 8:
            self.cooked_string = "charcoal"
        elif self.cooked_level > 5:
            self.cooked_string = "Well-done"
        elif self.cooked_level > 3:
            self.cooked_level = "Medium"
        else:
            self.cooked_string = "raw"
    def addCondiemnet(self, condiment):
        self.condiments.append(condiment)

myDog = HotDog()
print myDog
print "Cooking my Hot Dog for 4 minutes...."
myDog.cook(4)
print myDog
print "Cooking hot dog for 3 more Minutes"
myDog.cook(3)
print myDog
print "What happens if I cook it for 10 more minutes?"
myDog.cook(10)
print myDog
print "Now, im going to add some stuff to my hot dog"
myDog.addComdiment("ketchup")
myDog.addComdiment("More ketchup")
myDog.addComdiment("AND More ketchup")
print myDog
```

And if I run it, I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Python Programs\Chapter 1\AdvancedHOTDOG.py", line 34, in <module>
    myDog.cook(3)
  File "C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Python Programs\Chapter 1\AdvancedHOTDOG.py", line 16, in cook
    self.cooked_level=self.cooked_level+time
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

If you know the Problem then please reply.

Comment: The error message is clear, I think.

Comment: also you have typo in `def addCondiemnet()` it should be `def  addCondiment()` and when you call it `myDog.addComdiment()` it should be `myDog.addCondiment()`.

Comment: Yes thanks very much , it may be obvious for you , I have been  programming for a month and couldnt spot the error. So thx for your input

Comment: @Hijinxx, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for better understanding how SO works.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is line 22:

```
self.cooked_level = "Medium"
```

you are assigning a string to self.cook_level.

that line should be:

```
 self.cooked_string = "Medium"
```